# tensorflow model returning a value error when executed in jupyter notebook but runs well in coursera notebook

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

i am new to tensorflow, i have installed it but running code like this:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np 
    X = tf.constant(np.array([-7.0, -4.0, -1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0]))
    
    y = tf.constant(np.array([3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0, 24.0]))
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([ tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) ])
    
    model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.mae, optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), metrics = ['mae'])
    
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=5)
```

its returning a value error. when i tried to run this code using coursera notebook where i took a machine learning learning course, it runs fine but on my computer it gives a value error.

Comment: What is the actual error mesage, verbatim?

Answer (score 0):

Danse layer requires your input to be in 2 dimention. try the following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
X = tf.constant(np.array([-7.0, -4.0, -1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0]))
y = tf.constant(np.array([3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0, 24.0]))
X = np.reshape(X, (-1, 1)) # Reshape X to have shape (8, 1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([ tf.keras.layers.Dense(1) ])
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.mae, optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), metrics = ['mae'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=5)
```